# Store input radio selections when submit is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to store in my js file which radio option for each radio name was selected as well as store the Username that was entered. Here is my form

```
<form id="newPlayer">
                    Username:<br>
                     <input type="text" name="user"/><br>
                    Please Choose a Class: <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="class"/>Archer
                    <input type="radio" name="class"/>Mage
                    <input type="radio" name="class"/>Warrior
                    <br>
                    Please Choose a Race: <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="race"/>Orc
                    <input type="radio" name="race"/>Elf
                    <input type="radio" name="race"/>Human
                    <input type="radio" name="race"/>Worg
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

EDIT:
When I try to target the submit button for a click function it causes my page to reload instead of making the form fadeOut

```
var userInput;
var classInput;
var raceInput;

$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#newPlayer').fadeOut(500);
    userInput = $('input[name="user"]').val();
    classInput = $('input[name="class"]:checked').val();
    raceInput = $('input[name="race"]:checked').val();
});
```

Comment: You need something to store it in... localStorage, cookies, a database...?

Comment: localStorage is what I'll be using, whoever is downvoting, please explain why so I can correct it.

Comment: @Shniper can you tell a bit more of what you are trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: @AndréGumieri I would like to store the option selected as a variable, I assume I need to give each radio a value and then call upon that in js. I know how to get the value for the text input but I don't know how to for the radio input

Comment: @Shniper i've put an answer

Comment: Not the downvoter but I'm guessing it's because you didn't even have the HTML for the radio buttons correct, which would indicate you didn't research before posting. This is a mix between a very basic HTML question and many other pieces, along with no indication of where you wanted to store the data in the question. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps. First, you will have to put values on those inputs

```
<form id="newPlayer">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="user"/><br>
    Please Choose a Class: <br>
    <input value="archer" type="radio" name="class"/>Archer
    <input value="mage" type="radio" name="class"/>Mage
    <input value="warrior" type="radio" name="class"/>Warrior
    <br>
    Please Choose a Race: <br>
    <input value="orc" type="radio" name="race"/>Orc
    <input value="elf" type="radio" name="race"/>Elf
    <input value="human" type="radio" name="race"/>Human
    <input value="worg" type="radio" name="race"/>Worg
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then, using jQuery, a simple .val() will do the job:

```
var class_val = $('input[name="class"]:checked').val();
var race = $('input[name="race"]:checked').val();
var user = $('input[name="user"]').val();
```

After that, you just need to put in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('class', class_val);
localStorage.setItem('race', race);
localStorage.setItem('user', user);
```

To access those values in the future, you do that

```
var stored_class = localStorage.getItem('class');
var stored_race = localStorage.getItem('race');
var stored_user = localStorage.getItem('user');
```

To make things happens on submit, you add an submit event to the form, like that:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    // Get values
    var class_val = $('input[name="class"]:checked').val();
    ...

    // Store values
    localStorage.setItem('class', class_val);
    ...

    // Avoid form submit
    return false;
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. I suppose my main problem resides with making this all happen when I click submit. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Shniper you should be doing the submit event instead of the click. That way everything you want to do will happen before the form is sent. The fadeout you use in the example will not work since it's async.

Comment: even with your code and without the fadeOut, clicking submit is causing my page to reload for some reason.

Comment: The reason is because forms do that. If you don't want to refresh, put a return false at the end of submit event. I'll update the answer

Comment: Okay thank you, that works now, the problem is I have an animation that occurs on document ready and the form appears after the animation occurs, so when the page refreshed after clicking submit it basically created a looping form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110316/discussion-between-shniper-and-andre-gumieri).

Comment: It's hard to evolve on that since I don't fully understand what exactly you are doing and how it should behave. Maybe if you explain a little better what steps should happen after clicking to submit will help

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use localStorage.
For example:

```
//Make sure to set the selection variable to a object that contains the selections made by the user.
function save() {

    //This will save the current settings as an object to the localStorage.
    localStorage.selections = JSON.stringify(selections) ;

}

function load() {

    if (!localStorage.selections) {

        alart("No saves found.") ;
        return false ;

    }

    selections = JSON.parse(localStorage.selections) ;

}
```

Read more about localStorage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).